# Replace single quotes for insert to MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, string, jdbc, quotes

I have a task to replace single quotes for insert to MYSQL database and have following code:

```
String str = "A Linux's distributions";

        if (str.contains("'")) {
            str.replace("'", "''");
        }
```

But, this condition is not working. I sure that the solution is very simple ...

Comment: And why don't you just use prepared statements instead?

Comment: I know about the possibility of PreparedStatement and using it, but I get an error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: That is probably because you use `executeUpdate(String)` instead of `executeUpdate()` (**no parameter**). Maybe you should have asked a question about that problem instead (even though it gets asked regularly, it is pretty hard to find). **Do not manually escape the strings**.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I'm using the construction: PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.executeUpdate(sql); and I trying as you said: statement.executeUpdate(); but I getting same error. Do you have any thought about it?

Comment: I'd suggest you post a separate question with the code, **including the query as defined in Java** and the exact error message you receive.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are `immutable` in java. You need to assign it to a variable.

```
 String str = "A Linux's distributions";
 String str_new = "";
 if (str.contains("'")) 
 {
    str_new  = str.replace("'", "''");
 }
```